# Is is possible to send data from the template to the script with Vue.js ? (Inverse of v-bind)

Tags: vue.js

I want to know if it's possible to send the current data in v-for loop (in template) to , for example, a function in methods.

```
<li v-for="annonce in annonces">

    <article>
    //Here for example I want to send annonce.categorie to the methods 
    //object of the component to change the color in function of the 
    //anonce.categorie string
        <a v-bind:style="['color' : {{getColorCat(annonce)}}]"> 
        {{annonce.categorie}}
        </a> 
    </article>

</li>
```

**EDIT**
Just add the function with the parameter to send in v-bind:style, and create a method that return the string color in function of the current element in the loop.

```
<a v-bind:style="getStyle(annonce)">{{annonce.categorie}}</a>


  methods:{

    getStyle(annonce) {
    return { color: this.getColorCat(annonce) };
    },

    getColorCat(annonce) {

      switch(annonce.categorie)
      {
        case this.categories[0] :
        return 'limegreen'
        break;

        case this.categories[1] :
        return 'grey'
        break;

        case this.categories[2] :
        return 'deepskyblue'
        break;

        case this.categories[3] :
        return '#E3E01F'
        break;

        case this.categories[4] :
        return 'silver'
        break;

        case this.categories[5] :
        return 'pink'
        break;

        case this.categories[6] :
        return 'red'
        break;

        case this.categories[7] :
        return 'green'
        break;

        case this.categories[8] :
        return 'purple'
        break;

        case this.categories[9] :
        return 'magenta'
        break;
        default :
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that in a straightforward manner

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in items">
        {{getText(index)}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

and in the methods

```
methods: {
    getText(index) {
        return someFunctionOf(index);
    }
}
```

**Updated to add:**

You can also use methods to set attribute values, but the syntax in your example is wrong. There are several ways to fix it, but one approach is:

```
<a v-bind:style="getStyles(annonce)">
```

and then return an object with relevant styles

```
methods: {
    getStyles(annonce) {
        return { color: getColorCat(annonce) };
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you for the very fast answer. I test it now in my code.

Comment: <a v-bind:style="['color' : 
         {{getColorCat(annonce)}}]">{{annonce.categorie}}</a>

Comment: Is is possible to do that ? I want to change the color of {{annonce.categorie}} in function of the string annonce.categorie.

Comment: What you want to do is certainly possible, but your syntax is not correct. Maybe check out the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-Inline-Styles)